# Compare two columns/rows for exact matches and highlight differences

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet where I want to compare multiple columns and rows for matches.

I would like to identify records in the excel file where the value/s for a given row match the value/values for another given row.

For example
Find all rows in the array where value from column b and c exact match another row in the array for column b and c.

Once I have found all the rows where value from b and c match then compare the values from column a for those rows.  Highlight the row if the values from a differ.

```
ColA    ColB    ColC    
789     12345   abcde    highlight this row  
456     45678   kjioij  
123     12345   abcde    highlight this row
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data starts in cell A1, you would use this formula for the conditional format rule: `=COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1,$A:$A,"<>"&$A1)`